# Multiplying or dividing the values of fields in Node.js / Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to perform server-side calculations (in Node.JS/Firestore) that allows me to calculate an average and store in a separate field, without doing reading the document first?

I have two fields containing a `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment()` value, and would like to divide them to identify the average. (The reason why I don't want to do this client-side, if possible, is because I want to do other calculations with that average.)

```
        'totalgallons': firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(sum),
        'numberdays': firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
        'averagegallons': ?;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will either have to do this math on the client by reading the document first, or do it automatically on the backend with Cloud Functions.  If you don't trust the client, then your most feasible option is a [Firestore trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) that runs in response to the update from the client.  It will receive the new contents of the document (with the values of the increments), and you can then do whatever math you want, and update the document with any new values.